# How to access OAuth2-secured Spring cloud config server when using spring.config.import?

Tags: java, spring, oauth, spring-cloud-config

I have a Spring Cloud configuration server that is secured with OAuth2 and use the old-style (pre-Spring 2.4) bootstrap approach to bind to the config server. In order to make it use an OAuth2RestTemplate I implemented a custom `ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator` that sets the rest template, configured via `spring.factories` (I found a few examples out there that showed how to do this):

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigClientOAuth2BootstrapConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator configServicePropertySourceLocator() {
        ConfigClientProperties clientProperties = configClientProperties();
        ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator locator = new ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator(clientProperties);
        locator.setRestTemplate(oauth2RestTemplate());
        
        return locator;
    }

    [...]
}
```

META-INF/spring.factories:

```
org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration=\
com.example.config.ConfigClientOAuth2BootstrapConfiguration
```

Everything works fine that way.

But I would like to use the new Spring Boot Config Data method of import via `spring.config.import=optional:configserver:` instead which got introduced in 2.4 (doing away with bootstrap.properties, and the need for `spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap`), but cannot find any documentation or examples on how to set a custom Rest Template in this case.

Does anyone have an example (or link to documentation) on how this could be done? Or maybe it's not possible?

Comment: I have this same need. I need to override the class that does the magic and call a config server protected by oauth.  The import mechanism support a type of authentication but it is not oauth.

Comment: Maybe in boot  2.7 or 3.0, there is some ingenious answer for this. I am running simultaneous branches of those right now. I hacked a way around this issue but it doesn't load first like spring.config.import does. A custom implementation class would be just ideal.

Comment: @chrislhardin Plz share a minimal reproduceable codebase.